# Adding a user in wordpress with wp_insert_user doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to programmaticaly insert a user in wordpress using form input as account details. My code to do this looks like this:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $_POST["post_email"],
    'first_name'    =>  $_POST["post_voornaam"],
    'last_name'    =>  $_POST["post_achternaam"],
    'user_email'   =>  $_POST["post_email"],
    'user_pass'   =>  $_POST["password_confirm"]
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

add_user_meta( $user_id, 'klant_id', $klant_id );
```

As you see I'm also using a user meta field after I actually create the account. Sadly none of this works. Does anyone have any idea why this is failing?

It doesn't seem to return an errors either.

Comment: Make sure all of your values are what they should be. `var_dump($_POST);` `var_dump($user_id);`

Comment: `wp_insert_user` returns a [`WP_Error`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object.  If you inspect the value of `$user_id` after creating the user this will probably tell you why it isn't working, or give the ID if it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your post values. var_dump($_POST). 
if  you have all of post values,then try get_error_message() function to get errors  messages  while inserting the user.

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $_POST["post_email"],
    'first_name'    =>  $_POST["post_voornaam"],
    'last_name'    =>  $_POST["post_achternaam"],
    'user_email'   =>  $_POST["post_email"],
    'user_pass'   =>  $_POST["password_confirm"]
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;


if( is_wp_error( $user_id  ) ) {
    echo $return->get_error_message();
}

add_user_meta( $user_id, 'klant_id', $klant_id );
```